# Why Row in Pyspark Works in Pandas UDF Not Outside

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I didnt know exactly how to entitle this :)

The following code works where I am testing how I can mimic a grouped pandas UDF, inspired by this: https://pages.databricks.com/rs/094-YMS-629/images/so_dev_survey_2019.html

```
pd_small = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3],'col2':[4,5,6]})

sdf_small = spark.createDataFrame(pd_small)
sdf_small = sdf_small.repartition(3)

X_columns = list(pd_small.columns)



def test_mp(rows):
    rows_pd = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=X_columns)
    array = rows_pd.values
    return [Row(*([float(f) for f in array[i]])) for i in range(len(array))]
    


sdf_small.rdd.mapPartitions(test_mp).toDF(X_columns).show()
```

However, if I run this outside of the function, there is an error. Why does it work in the function?

```
[Row(*([float(f) for f in pd_small.values[i]])) for i in range(len(pd_small.values))]
```

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: Your code have worked normally here, check if you didn't override any of these variables before